# Need to remove Dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot

But the problem I'm facing is: Installed the Ubuntu in UEFI but the windows BIOS was in legacy, now I can't access windows " says it can't find file" and cannot download anything meaning in Ubuntu again same issue. I want to remove everything and start from beginning and install Dual-boot again.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! The general process would be: Install Windows (which will insist on using the entire disk) ⇢ Resize the Windows partition ⇢ Install Ubuntu. Alternatively, depending on what you use each OS for, it may make sense to run the less-used OS in a virtual machine.

Comment: UEFI install moves boot flag to ESP - efi system partition. Windows has to have boot flag on its partition with boot files. You can use gparted or Windows tools to move boot flag back to Windows boot partition. If converting everything to UEFI, it will convert drive from MBR to gpt, totally erasing it, so make sure you have good backups.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall Windows 10 before reinstalling Ubuntu. This would be a good opportunity to accept the [free upgrade from Windows 10 to Windows 11](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/upgrade-to-windows-11-faq-fb6206a2-1a0f-448a-80f1-8668ee5b2bf9). Installing Windows will use the entire disk. After reinstalling Windows, boot from the live Ubuntu USB and the Ubuntu installer will guide you through the step of allocating disk space for the new Ubuntu installation.